# Is gearsandcogs extension still working in lastest AIR versions 32.0+?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, android-native-library

I have a project in AS3 using package com.gearsandcogs.air.extensions.
When a try to compile a Native Android APK, shows this error:

"An implementation for native extension 'com.gearsandcogs.air.extensions.PackageManager' required by the application was not found for the target platform."

In the description XML:

```
<extensions>
    <extensionID>com.gearsandcogs.air.extensions.PackageManager</extensionID>
</extensions>
```

If I comment the "extensionID", compiles the apk without errors.

Sugestions to solve this or other PackageManager alternative?

*Harman SDK 33.1 with VSCode+ActionScript & MXML Extensions*

Thanks!
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Our PackageManager ANE is available for AIR 33+

https://github.com/distriqt/ANE-PackageManager

If there's any functionality missing that you need just contact us through the repository and we'll work on getting it added for you.

Comment: Hello Michael!
Thank you very much for your return.
I will take a look at your material and give you feedback as soon as possible!
Thanks alot!